# Is $\{u\#v \mid u\not=v\}$ context-free?

Tags: context-free, automata, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata

Is the following language context-free?

$$
\{u\#v\in\Sigma^* \mid u\not=v \text{ and } u,v\in\{0,1\}^*\}
$$

You can assume $\{0,1,\#\}\subseteq\Sigma$.

Unnecessary background information: I am grading papers, and a student cited that this language is context-free to state that it is decidable. My intuition says that the language is not context free, but if someone could confirm this for me or even point me to a proof, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Actually, the background information is quite useful, thank you for that.

Comment: Have you looked at our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/843/755)?  Have you tried any of the methods listed there, such as the pumping lemma?  We expect you to make a serious effort on your own before asking and to show us in the question what you've tried.

Comment: To answer your question: yes, it is context-free. The linked question contains a proof. The idea is pretty simple: for $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$, the language equals $\{ \Sigma^n 0 \Sigma^* \# \Sigma^n 1 \Sigma^*, \Sigma^n 1 \Sigma^* \# \Sigma^n 0 \Sigma^*, \Sigma^n \# \Sigma^{n+1} \Sigma^* , \Sigma^* \Sigma^{n+1} \# \Sigma^n : n \geq 0 \}$.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for asking a question that had already been asked!